# jQRangeSlider not working with Bootstrap? version conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, date-range

EDIT: Question got solved. It was a careless beginner mistake.

I want to use [jQRangeSlider](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/index.html) plugin in my Nodejs / Express based webapp. It has a beautiful data range slider ([here's a simple jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghusse/vM844/)) that I intend to use in combination with the [Bootstrap Datepicker Plugin](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). However, I cannot get this working, i.e. nothing is displayed where the slider should be.

What's confusing for me is that there are no errors in the console (neither powershell / firefox dev-console). 
I'm wondering if it's a version or conflicting issue with the plugins or the dependencies.
Posting some code, I hope it's enough.

(I am using [PUG templating engine](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html), so my HTML is PUG-style syntax)

Used dependencies: (grouped for overview while debugging this)

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title

//- JQUERY
script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js')
//- JQUERY UI
link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css')
script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js')
script(src='/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js')
//- Date range slider
script(src='/javascripts/jQDateRangeSlider-min.js')
//link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/iThing-min.css')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/classic-min.css')
//- BOOTSTRAP DATE PICKER
script(type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js")
link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css')   
//- BOOTSTRAP
script(src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css')
//- BOOTSTRAP TOGGLE
link(href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet")
script(src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js")
//- custom CSS
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
body
  block content
```

Placed in my HTML form:

```
div.form-group
      label.control-label(for="myslider") where the slider?
      div#myslider
```

Initializing the slider as documented:

```
$("#myslider").dateRangeSlider();
```

The result:

[image]

Hopefully this is not confusing - I can't post the entire thing. But other form elements are working this way (i.e. datepicker, other form inputs) The $("#myslider").dateRangeSlider() function is called (I checked by removing the dependency which throws an error in the console.)

I don't know how to further debug this and I will gladly provide more detailed information if necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put the script tag with $("#myslider").dateRangeSlider(); AFTER the div#myslider. Embarrassing to a great extent. It's working as expected now.